# Can I lose track of banned users who signed in from FB login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app in which users can sign up via many auth providers among which Facebook Login (using facebook SDK).
Everything works fine but I was wondering if there's a way banned users (ToS violators) can get to access the web app?

For example, can they do that using the [remove app functionality](https://www.facebook.com/help/170585223002660) from their FB account settings or some other way where they could seamingly change their identity making them look like new users from the FB API (new IDs because of some change they made to their account,...) thus being able to sign up again on my app with the same technically banned facebook account?

Comment: _"new IDs because of some change they made to their account"_ - users can not do anything to change their app-scoped user id, it will stay the same.

Comment: I thought that there would be generation of new IDs because I've once changed some info from my FB profile and that resulted in a loss of an account on an app I linked with FB. Thanks for the reply